# Entity Framework SET IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to force the ID value for a new entity in EF when we have an auto-incrementing ID column, i.e. use SET IDENTITY_INSERT behaviour through EF?

Our requirement is that our create form must always show a new, unique ID for the object we're creating on the empty form before it is filled in or saved. The idea is that this ID can be out read to someone over the phone and then the user can complete and save the form after the call is complete. We could reserve an ID by inserting an empty row into the database there and then, but we have unique columns and FKs; instead I've made a 'next ID' table that we increment with locks for safety, and I test this against the top ID in the object table too to be careful. The idea was to then force the use of this new ID when we write back the entity - but I can't see how to get EF to do it.

Is that possible - is it just something I've missed? I don't think the ID even makes it down to the insert so I don't think manually calling SET IDENTITY_INSERT around the SaveChanges would help.

Or do I have to do something else? I can see alternatives:

- Change our ID column to not be an identity and take manual control of it all: there's a table ID inheritance here so this is potentially tricky too.
- Separate DB ID and user-visible ID into a separate column, and record our unique ID there.
- Empty row to reserve the ID, as above; might need some nullability changes, and amending our data read code to ignore these records.

Thanks! This is EF4 (using an EDMX and generated classes not POCOs), and against SQL Server 2008 in case that matters.

Comment: The only way to guarantee the ID is to insert it -- playing with `SET IDENTITY INSERT` isn't going to fix the fact you'll deal with potential duplicates before toggling the functionality back to deal with constraints.  Is this really just an issue with needing sequential numbers?

Comment: @OMG Ponies Yeah, maybe that will be the way to go after all. Duplicate IDs to insert will definitely be the exception case, though - the sequential new IDs that we're feeding back were generated in a different table with locks etc. so unless things go unexpectedly wrong will be unique.

Comment: If you determine the new values yourself - what do you need the `IDENTITY` specification for, in that case???

Comment: @marc_s I guess we don't really, but this is an enhancement to an already-built system and I was hoping to keep changes to existing stuff to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Guid as primary key. Nothing to do with auto-increment, no concurrency pitfalls etc. You just create the Guid at the moment you create the form. Hand it over to a caller and fill in the form afterwards. When the form is cancelled, no problem. When the form is finished create the entity with the created Guid set the other values of the entity object, apply it to the (a) context and SaveChanges()...

Comment: Thanks. The ID has to be read to a human being, though, so the simpler the better. I don't see the advantage of using this over a separate incremented number (which is a problem I've already solved anyway) in a new column: we'll still have to modify all our search + lookup code to search the new values instead, etc. If you meant the table primary key then there FKRs to this table (plus the ID inheritance I mentioned) so I'd rather keep that as integer - again apart from the randomness I don't see an advantage here.

Comment: Just make sure **NOT** to let it become the **clustering key** on your table - that would be horribly inefficient and very very bad for your database..

Comment: I now see the problem more clearly...when ID is created by EF and is in the primary key it's not possible to change it afterwards I guess...Maybe when you detach the entity from the context...I work with Self Tracking Entities...a solution there could be to StopTracking the entity to change a value that's in the primary key. Tough one though!

Comment: "Separate DB ID and user-visible ID into a separate column, and record our unique ID there."

-> Might be the best approach!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives that wont alter your schema

1. Use EF Transaction

You can call context.SaveChanges() and get the autoincremented primary key. Once the process is completed you can commit the transaction. If the transaction is cancelled or there is an error/exception, you can always rollback so you wont have holes/dirty-data in your rows. I suggest you use the singleton pattern and pass the same transaction/context to whatever methods or screens to complete the process.

2. Just add an additional status: Draft

Save empty form as draft with saved ID, then proceed to edit the form with the information. Once complete save the form as final/ready. If you wont proceed to save the form, you can always recycle the draft.