# Unique number identifier generation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have to create logic for generation unique number identifier for records in database. id, generated in database is a separate column.

At this moment, when user calls "create record" action, I save new record, get its database id, generate record number using this id, then put it to the edit form.
Using this way means that all entity fields should be nullable to save record to database.

I don't like this way. I know that should be better way.

Is there a better practice to generate unique number identifier? What is possibility of generating non-unique random numbers?

Thank you

Comment: Jeff Atwood has an article on his blog about GUID genrate, you can reference it. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/equipping-our-ascii-armor.html

Comment: [I had a similar problem a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761668/entity-framework-set-identity-insert) but didn't come up with a good solution. In my case we wanted to be able to read the IDs over the phone whilst filling in the form. Some answers suggested using GUIDs, which will be unique but weren't suitable for my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern that you're using, of saving an empty record simply to get the ID, is not a good one.

The standard approach, and the one that I'd recommend, is for Create Record to simply display an empty form (the ID at this point will typically be 0). The user fills in the form and the data is only committed to the database when the user clicks Save. The ID should be an IDENTITY column.

A problem with your approach is that if users do not complete the form, you end up with lots of incomplete records in your database. And, of course, it makes it much more difficult to handle data validation and integrity.

An alternative approach, if you *really* must display the ID to the user, is to have a separate table containing a row with a "Next Record ID" column. This column can be incremented and returned as an atomic operation and used to populate the ID of your new record. You still don't create the real record, just increment this "Next Record ID" in your Create Record action. Using this approach, you can use the same approach for multiple entities by having separate rows for each in this "Record IDs" table. Bear in mind that if the user does not ultimately save the record to the database, an ID will still have been 'used up'. The numbers will still be unique and will be chronological but won't necessarily be contiguous.

Comment: I tried that second approach a while back. That does mean the ID column on the first table can no longer be an identity (because AFAIK [EF doesn't support SET IDENTITY INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761668/entity-framework-set-identity-insert)) but that's not too much of a problem.

Comment: But how do I should increment Next Record ID without saving record to database?

Comment: @xwrs, the Next Record ID is simply a numeric value in a separate table to your entity. There's no problem with updating the row containing the Next Record ID in order to derive the ID for your entity - but don't insert the entity into *its* table until the user hits 'Save' on the data entry screen.

Comment: @Rup, that's right, you're manually implementing an equivalent to an Identity column, so the ID mustn't be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it, but, if you are using the `uniqueidentifier` data type in your database, that translates to `Guid` in C#, so you can do:

```
public Guid CreateRecord(MyObject model) {

    Guid newId = Guid.NewGuid();

    MyTable tbl = new MyTable();
    tbl.guid = newId;

    // ... other columns

    db.MyTable.AddObject(tbl);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return newId;
}
```

though what I normally do, is having the PrimaryKey as `int` and add a `uniqueidentifier` field named `guid` (that I use it publically instead the `column_id`) and remember to index that column.

Comment: Guid is not a number, but I need a nine-digit number for additional record identification before saving it to database.

Comment: Guid is a random number (when you use `Guid.NewGuid();`) that exists in `C#` and in `SQL` (when using `uniqueidentifier` data type)... why not just using that?

Comment: @xwrs, under the covers a Guid is a 128 bit number

Answer (score 1):

Code for Table..

```
CREATE TABLE TblTransactions(
    TId varchar(8),
    TName varchar(50)
)
```

C# Code Behind…

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = GenerateId("TblTransactions", "TId", 8, "TRN");
// insert the id along with data in the table
    Response.Write(id);
}

public string GenerateId(string TableName, string ColumnName, int ColumnLength, string Prefix)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.;integrated security=true;database=EBissCard");
    string Query, Id;
    int PrefixLength, PadLength;
    PrefixLength = Convert.ToInt32(Prefix.Length);
    PadLength = ColumnLength - PrefixLength;
    Query = "SELECT '" + Prefix + "' + REPLACE(STR(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(" + ColumnName + "," + Convert.ToString(PrefixLength + 1) + "," + PadLength + ") AS INTEGER))+1," + PadLength + "),' ',0) FROM " + TableName;

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    con.Open();
    if (com.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == "")
    {
        Id = Prefix;
        for (int i = 1; i <= PadLength - 1; i++)
        {
            Id += "0";
        }
        Id += "1";
    }
    else
    {
        Id = Convert.ToString(com.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    con.Close();
    return Id;
}
```

Comment: Is this is an implementation of Steve's second idea, use a simple table to record newly issued IDs and store the actual data in a different table?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class from .net itself.

Comment: The problem is it needs to be unique against anything already in the database but also unique against all other users who might also have the web form open. You'd need a lot more than just a random number to guarantee this.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to generate a unique number for a record is to use the time() in milliseconds (since a reference point of time, say, 01/01/2010).

However, if there are 2 records that are simultaneously getting updated, this may cause an issue. To solve this problem, if each of the user can be assigned a number (when creating the userID), a combination (concatenation) of that "user number" and time in milliseconds will give you the unique number you need.

Comment: Actually I have to show record's id to user before saving it to database.